# Swapping between control schemes mid game

Tags: xcode, accelerometer, d-pad

Right, I am coding a game where you must navigate a maze using either a D-Pad or the device's accelerometer. I have successfully coded both methods, but how can I use an in game 'switch' to swap between the two?

Comment: keep a flag somewhere which points at whatever scheme is active, and ignore inputs from the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean flags to toggle which controls should work.

Some pseudo-Swift code for an example:

```
Bool shouldUseDPad

func changeControlScheme() {
    if shouldUseDPad {
        shouldUseDPad = false
    } else {
        shouldUseDPad = true
    }
}

func theDPadListener(dPadEvent) {
    if shouldUseDPad {
        doStuff(dPadEvent)
    }
}

func theAccelerometerListener(accelEvent) {
    if !shouldUseDPad {
        doStuff(accelEvent)
    }
}
```